# Struggling to understand FOR loop

Tags: azure, terraform

The following code successfully deploys 2 x log analytic workspaces in different regions in azure in their own region based resource groups

I'm struggling to understand how this FOR loop works

Is someone able to break it down for me please. I have looked at the official documentation but I'm still not getting it.

thanks

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
  resource_groups = {
    for k, v in var.workspaces : k => {
      location = v.location
    }
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "workspaces" {
  for_each = local.resource_groups

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces" {
  for_each = var.workspaces

  name                = each.key
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[each.key].name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = each.value.retention_in_days
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "workspaces" {
  type = map(object({
    location          = string
    retention_in_days = number
  }))
  default = {
    workspace1 = {
      location          = "australiasoutheast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    workspace2 = {
      location          = "australiaeast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    # Add more workspaces as needed
  }
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
# Define outputs
output "workspace_ids" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces[*].id
}

output "workspace_names" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces[*].name
}

output "resource_group_ids" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].id
}

output "resource_group_names" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].name
}

output "resource_group_locations" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].location
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `local.resource_groups` is **redundant**. It does not do anything useful, except it removes `retention_in_days` from `var.workspaces`. Normally you would use `var.workspaces` directly:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "workspaces" {
  for_each = local.workspaces

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value.location
}
```

Comment: thanks Marcin, I have a follow up to this which I will be posting soon as well.